# Is there a name for isomorphism-preserving functions?

Tags: functions, set-theory, terminology, cardinals

Is there a name for isomorphism-preserving functions in the sense that whenever $x,y$ are sets of the same cardinality, so are $f(x)$ and $f(y)$?

For instance, working within the NBG set theory, denote by $\mathbf{S}$ the class of sets, and consider the function $f:\mathbf{S}\rightarrow\mathbf{S}$ satisfying for every $x \in \mathbf{S}$, $f(x) = \mathbb{P}x$. Then $f$ is isomorphism-preserving, since whenever $y, z \in \mathbf{S}$ have the same cardinality, so do their powersets.

On the other hand, let $a, a', b \in \mathbf{S}$ be such that $a$ and $a'$ are disjoint sets of the same, non-zero cardinality, and let $g:a\rightarrow b$. Consider the function $f':\mathbf{S}\rightarrow\mathbf{S}$ satisfying for every $x \in \mathbf{S}$, $f'(x) = g[x]$, i.e. $f'(x)$ is the image of $x$ under $g$, which, by the replacement axiom, is a set. Then
$$
|f'(a)| = |g[a]| \neq 0 = |\emptyset| = |g[a']| = |f'(a')|.
$$

Comment: What's wrong with "cardinality preserving"?

Comment: I would expect a "cardinality-preserving" function to map each set to a set of the same cardinality, i.e., $|X| = |f(X)|$ for all sets $X$. Instead, I would say that the powerset function "respects isomorphism".

Comment: In your second example, I guess you intended to pick $a$ and $a'$ to be disjoint sets?

Comment: Two small remarks: (1) The class of all sets is commonly denoted by $V$. (2) I have seen power sets denoted by $P,\wp,\cal P$, and even by $S$, but hardly ever by $\Bbb P$.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that I follow your "on the other hand" example.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Corrected. Thanks.